# Run a bash file with parameters with Go

Tags: bash, go

I am trying to run a bash script that has parameters like so:

```
./test.sh param1 param2
```

bash file

```
param1=$1
param2=$2

echo $param1
echo $param2
```

However it does not work but it will work if the params are not there.

```
cmd, _ := exec.Command("/bin/sh", fmt.Sprintf("./test.sh %s %s","test1","test2")).Output()
```

But if I change the bash script to do something else without passing anything into it, then it works.

```
cmd, _ := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "./test.sh").Output()
```

How can I pass parameters into a bash file with Go?

Comment: `sh` should never be used to run a `bash` file. sh and bash are two different shells -- even on operating systems where they're symlinked, starting bash under the name `sh` disables some of its features.

Comment: The quotes are not quite right, as can be seen from the syntax highlighting here in the post.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you were Doing It Right, you'd have a shebang in your script and wouldn't specify an explicit interpreter at all in the caller.

Comment: That is to say, make the script start with `#!/bin/sh` (if it's really a `sh` script instead of a `bash` script), give it executable permissions, and then start `exec.Command('./test.sh', "test1", "test2")`. (Ideally, you shouldn't have a `.sh` extension on the filename either -- see [commandname extensions considered harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/) for an extensive essay on the topic; using extensions means you can't _change_ your script's interpreter without making the extension misleading or also changing every caller).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sh` expects *the name of a script to run* as its argument. You don't run `sh './test.sh test1 test2'` at a shell, you run `sh ./test.sh test1 test2`. The equivalent to that in Go is:

```golang
// KINDA BAD: Doesn't let the script choose its own interpreter
cmd, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "./test.sh", "test1", "test2")
```

If you were passing *a shell script* as an argument, that would be akin to the shell command `sh -c './test.sh test1 test2'` -- notice the `-c` argument. It's very bad practice (introduces serious security bugs), and you shouldn't ever do this, but if you were going to, it would look like:

```golang
// VERY BAD: Introduces serious security bugs if arguments are parameterized
cmd, err := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "./test.sh test1 test2")
```

---

But you shouldn't do any of that. Change your script to have a shebang:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
param1=$1
param2=$2

echo "$param1"
echo "$param2"
```

...save it as `yourscript` (no `.sh`!), set it to have executable permissions (`chmod +x yourscript`), and then run:

```golang
// GOOD: Lets your script choose its own interpreter
cmd, err := exec.Command("./yourscript", "test1", "test2")
```

Comment: awesome thanks. I knew it would be simple